# chgrp and chmod not working in cygwin (windows 8)

Tags: cygwin, chmod, chgrp

I work in "C:\Users\leyou\.ssh"

I need to chmod id_rsa to 600 as it's currently 644, but it has no effect.

Hence I tried "chgrp Users id_rsa" but it doesn't work neither and the group remains as "mkpasswd".

Edit: The above happens in a windows command.

When I try from the cygwin bash, chgrp and chmod work, but when I run "ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" it fails saying that id_rsa is 644 even though I get 600 through ls -la.

It doesn't make sense AT ALL...

Comment: It looks like a question for superuser.com (this site is about programming). See also: [Using Cygwin in Windows 8, chmod 600 does not work as expected?](http://superuser.com/questions/397288/using-cygwin-in-windows-8-chmod-600-does-not-work-as-expected) and [Bug in Cygwin Windows 8 group permissions](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2012-12/msg00007.html)

Comment: @ilya: ok i posted it to superuser. For the second link, I'm not using a bundled cygwin but the full install. Concerning the first one, the answer tells to use "chgrp -R Users ~/.ssh" but in my case this has no effect.